# Browser based image upload to S3 responds with missing uploaded_data on django production server

Tags: django, upload, amazon-s3

After a few days I managed to get browser based uploads to S3 working just fine on Django 1.5 and uploadify. The code works fine in development running the Django server. Upon deploying to my Webfaction server I now receive the following error.

> AttributeError at /upload/11/done 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'group'

The error is caused by the unquote_plus line in my view that handles the response from S3

```
post_response = request.POST['upload_data']
location_rexp = '<Location>(.*)</Location>'
content.file_url = unquote_plus(re.search(location_rexp, post_response).group(1))
```

I assume the reg ex is failing, as it is NoneType. This might be caused by what seems to be missing data in the post response [uploaded_data] - only on the production server. See below.

I'm not sure how to proceed. Am I missing something with the encoding?

```
[Django development server]
POST:
file_obj[size] = u'2647'
file_obj[id] = u'SWFUpload_0_0'
file_obj[filestatus] = u'-4'
file_obj[name] = u'Orange.gif'
file_obj[creationdate] = u'Sat Feb 09 2013 11:57:55 GMT+1100 (EST)'
upload_data = u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<PostResponse><Location>http://ash.mlsvideo.s3.amazonaws.com/assnow%2F1%2Fvideos%2FOrange.gif</Location><Bucket>ash.mlsvideo</Bucket><Key>assnow/1/videos/Orange.gif</Key><ETag>"2e133a52ef02d2a58b9f2640f9bdf65d"</ETag></PostResponse>'
file_obj[type] = u'.gif'
s3_response = u'true'


[Webfaction server]
POST:
file_obj[size] = u'1947'
file_obj[id] = u'SWFUpload_0_1'
file_obj[filestatus] = u'-4'
file_obj[name] = u'Strawberry.gif'
file_obj[creationdate] = u'Sat Feb 09 2013 11:57:55 GMT+1100 (EST)'
upload_data = u'CWS\t\xea`'
file_obj[type] = u'.gif'
s3_response = u'true'
```